# TypeError: unorderable types: atm() >= int()

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, overriding, typeerror

I have 3 classes, `ATM` (main class), `atmFees` (subclass of ATM) and transaction. I want to have my class `atmFees` inherit methods from the parent class `ATM`.

The atmFees class takes the `atm` object as a parameter, initializing with `atm.__init__(self, balance)`

I want to override the parent/super class's "withdrawal" method, modifying one of the parameters -- subtracting 50 cents from `amount` -- and then accessing the super method in `atm` with the new amount.

Doing so returns a `TypeError: unorderable types: atm() >= int()`

I have absolutely no idea what to do from here, I've changed almost everything but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import transaction
import random

class atm(object):

    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal
        self.transactionList = []

    def deposit(self, name, amount):
        self.__balance += amount
        ndt = transaction.Transaction(name, amount)
        self.transactionList.append(ndt)

    def withdraw(self, name, amount):
        if self.__balance >= amount:
            self.__balance -= amount
            nwt = transaction.Transaction(name, amount)
            self.transactionList.append(nwt)
        else:
            print('Uh oh, not enough money!')

    def get_balance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def __str__(self):
        string_return = "" 
        for transaction in self.transactionList:
            string_return += str(transaction) + "\n"
        string_return = '\n' + 'The balance is $' + format(self.__balance, ',.2f')
        return string_return

class atmFee(atm):

    def __init__(self, balance):
        atm.__init__(self, balance)

    def widthrawal(cls, name, amount):
        amount = amount - .50
        atm.widthrawal(cls, name, amount)

    def deposit():
        pass

def main():

    myATM = atm.atm(75)
    fees  = atm.atmFee(myATM)

    fees.withdraw("2250",30)
    fees.withdraw("1000",20)
    myATM.deposit("3035",10)

    print("Let's withdraw $40")
    if myATM.withdraw("Amazon Prime",40) == 0:
        print ("Oh noes! No more money!")

    print()
    print("Audit Trail:")
    print(myATM)

main();
```

**The full code is posted here:** 
https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/e2bd662d7ff83ca5ef61

Any guidance / help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might get better answers if you post a minimal code sample to reproduce the problem in the question. But it looks like to should look into Python's rich comparison methods (especially `__ge__`).

Comment: added the code where the error occurs. i'll check into the comparison methods.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means just what it says - you can't order an object and an integer. This is possible (for some reason) in Python 2, where the ordering is essentially arbitrary (for example, an empty dict `{}` is always greater than an integer, no matter how large...), but it is not in Python 3, because the comparison is meaningless.

Comment: I'm confused.  The Python 2 doc, specifically for CPython says that objects of different types are ordered by type name (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), so why is a `dict` object always > an `int`  (which is correct, I checked)?

Comment: @cdarke: "objects of different types except numbers". `int` is a number, and doesn't follow that rule.

Answer (score 1):

You create your ATM object like this:

```
myATM = atm.atm(75)
fees  = atm.atmFee(myATM)
```

So `myATM`, itself an ATM object, gets passed in to `atmFee.__init__` as the balance. In `withdraw`, you expect the balance to be a number and not an ATM object (if the comparison worked, the arithmetic you do on it would then fail). You almost certainly meant to set the balance to a number by creating the object like this:

```
fees = atm.atmFee(75)
```

Note that atmFee takes *exactly* the same constructor signature as the superclass (this isn't a rule, but it is how you've set it up here), so you should use it in the same way.

You are also switching between using `fees` and `myATM` in the rest of your code, which seems odd. It looks like you mean to be using `fees` in all cases, and don't actually need `myATM` at all.

Comment: works perfectly thanks. Question, I want to set/update the `balance` of the parent class ATM when initializing and making withdrawals, how come it isn't happening? I've called super (referencing ATM.method()) ...

Comment: For example, when i do a withdrawal using the atmFees class (which references the ATM method withdrawal()) it doesn't seem to record those transactions.

Comment: @markbratanov I can't see any reason for that at a cursory glance. You may want to post a new question, making sure you include code that shows you that the transactions aren't recorded.